# Move div/blocks vertically with animations

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

If i have divs / blocks

```
<ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">List Item 1  <button class="btn btn-default animate pull-right">Animate</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">List Item 2 <button class="btn btn-default animate pull-right">Animate</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">List Item 3  <button class="btn btn-default animate pull-right">Animate</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">List Item 4  <button class="btn btn-default animate pull-right">Animate</button></li>
      <li class="list-group-item clearfix">List Item 5  <button class="btn btn-default animate pull-right">Animate</button></li>
    </ul>
```

Onclick of button i want to reorder elements with ANIMATION, Like clicked/selected elements on top

1. List Item 5
2. List item 1
3. List item 2
4. List Item 3
5. List Item 4

On select of another item it has to be next to already moved item

1. List Item 5
2. List item 3
3. List item 1
4. List Item 2
5. List Item 4

How can we achieve this

[Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4xLC4pmmtcUVwa0mK1ie?p=preview)

But this is not moving to its positions perfectly. 
NOTE: Elements should move only on click. Not on drag and Drop

Comment: is duplicate is intended or . insertbefore and after adding unwanted . the same happening in the answer too!!

Comment: duplicate is not required. I will try to use below answer. Will modify to avoid duplicates

Comment: Not sure why duplicates are getting added. I have disabled clicking while it is animating. Solved problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example, when you click on a button, the list item moves to the top of the list. Because it uses the `live` function it only works in jQuery versions less than 1.9.

```
$("li").live("click", function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).closest("li");
    var listHeight = $("ul").innerHeight();
    var elemHeight = selectedItem.height();
    var elemTop = selectedItem.position().top;
    var moveUp = listHeight - (listHeight - elemTop);
    var moveDown = elemHeight;
    var listNum = selectedItem.attr("id");
    var listHtml = selectedItem.outerHTML();

    $("li").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == listNum) {
            return false;
        }
        $(this).animate( { "top": '+=' + moveDown }, 1000);
    });

    selectedItem.animate( { "top": '-=' + moveUp }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("ul").html(listHtml + $("ul").html());
        $("li").attr("style", "");
    });
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $(this).clone().wrap('<div></div>').parent().html();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zdhzefu5/1

Comment: .live is not a big problem. I have replaced it with .on and it is simply amazing.