# How to animate table Rows while swaping

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

this is the animation i am trying to do in html CSS and js
I have tried with transition and also with some animation properties  but don't know I am in right way  or not need help.

[image: how do I achieve this animation while swiping table rows]

this is the animation i am trying to do in html CSS and js
I have tried with transition and also with some animation properties  but don't know I am in right way  or not need help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                onClickMoveUPorDOWN();

                function onClickMoveUPorDOWN() {
                    targetToAppend = document.querySelector("#appendedBanners");

                    var btn_moveDOWN = [
                        ...document.getElementsByClassName("ClickDOWN"),
                    ];
                    var btn_moveUP = [
                        ...document.getElementsByClassName("ClickUP"),
                    ];
                    btn_moveUP.forEach((onebyone) => {
                        onebyone.addEventListener("click", ChangePositionUP);
                    });

                    btn_moveDOWN.forEach((onebyone) => {
                        onebyone.addEventListener("click", ChangePositionDOWN);
                    });
                }

                function ChangePositionUP() {

                    let currentElement = this.parentElement.parentElement; 
                    currentElement.classList.add("MovingUp");

                    let previosElement = currentElement.previousElementSibling;
                    previosElement.classList.add("MovingDown");
                    
                    
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        currentElement.classList.remove("MovingUp");
                        previosElement.classList.remove("MovingDown");
                    }, 300);


                    CurrentElement_TOMOVE = this.parentElement.parentElement;
                    // console.log(CurrentElement_TOMOVE);
                    activeClass =
                        document.getElementsByClassName("activelyMoving");
                                     
                    this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add(
                        "activelyMoving"
                    );
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        currentElement.classList.remove("activelyMoving");
                    }, 700);
                    // CurrentElement_TOMOVE =  closest(this, 'stoptillhere')
                    previousElement_TOMOVE =
                        CurrentElement_TOMOVE.previousElementSibling;
                    targetToAppend.insertBefore(
                        CurrentElement_TOMOVE,
                        previousElement_TOMOVE
                    );
                }

                function ChangePositionDOWN() {
                   let  currentElement = this.parentElement.parentElement;
                    currentElement.classList.add("MovingDown");

                   let nextElement  = currentElement.nextElementSibling;
                    nextElement.classList.add("MovingUp");

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        currentElement.classList.remove("MovingDown");
                        nextElement.classList.remove("MovingUp");    
                    }, 300);

                    CurrentElement_TOMOVE = this.parentElement.parentElement;
                   
                    this.parentElement.parentElement.classList.add(
                        "activelyMoving"
                    );
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        currentElement.classList.remove("activelyMoving");
                    }, 700);
                    nextElement_TOMOVE =
                        CurrentElement_TOMOVE.nextElementSibling;
                    // console.log(nextElement_TOMOVE);
                    targetToAppend.insertBefore(
                        nextElement_TOMOVE,
                        CurrentElement_TOMOVE
                    );
                }
            });
```

```css
.fa {
                width: 5px;
                height: 4px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
            .arrow {
                visibility: hidden;
                border: 1px solid #d4d4d499;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .arrow:hover {
                cursor: pointer !important;
            }
            /* tr {
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: #fafafc;
            } */
            tr:hover {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }
            tr:hover .arrow {
                animation: scale-up-center 0.2s;
                visibility: visible;
            }
            .activelyMoving {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                transform: scale(1);
                /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(100, 100, 100); */
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
            }
            .activelyMoving .arrow {
                visibility: visible;
            }
            .t-row{
                transition: all 0.3s;
            }
            .MovingUp{
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                transform: scale(1);
                /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(100, 100, 100); */
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);

            }
            .MovingDown{
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                transform: scale(1);
                /* box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgb(100, 100, 100); */
                box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px rgb(100, 100, 100);

            }

            /* @keyframes scale-up-center {
                0% {
                    transform: scale(0.5);
                }
                100% {
                    transform: scale(1);
                }
            }
            @keyframes slide-top {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                    transform: translateY(0);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
                    transform: translateY(-100px);
                }
            }
            @keyframes slide-bottom {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
                            transform: translateY(0);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: translateY(100px);
                            transform: translateY(100px);
                }
            } */

            /* @keyframes flip-horizontal-bottom {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
                    transform: rotateX(0);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                    transform: rotateX(-180deg);
                }
            } */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Table Row animation</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
        />

        
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container mt-3">
            <table class="table" id="table_appendHTML">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Rule Name</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>priority</th>
                        <th>status</th>
                        <th> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="appendedBanners" class="animate">
                    <tr id class="t-row">
                        <td>One</td>
                        <td>type 1</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickUP arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <span class="span span-1">1</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickDOWN arrow">
                                <i
                                    class="fa fa-chevron-down"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                ></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>...</td>
                    </tr>
    
                    <tr id class="t-row">
                        <td>two</td>
                        <td>type 2</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickUP arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <span
                                class="span span-2"
                                style=
                                >2</span
                            >
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickDOWN arrow">
                                <i
                                    class="fa fa-chevron-down"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                ></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>Active</td>
                        <td>...</td>

                    </tr>
    
                    <tr id class="t-row">
                        <td>three</td>
                        <td>type 3</td>
                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickUP arrow">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <span class="span span-3">3</span>
                            <button class="btn btn-sm ClickDOWN arrow">
                                <i
                                    class="fa fa-chevron-down"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                ></i>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>Paused</td>
                        <td>...</td>


                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        

        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33025814/move-div-blocks-vertically-with-animations) helps. The answer links to a jsfiddle which seems to be what you want. Though it doesn't use table.